# UpdatePanel not fixed during refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have an update panel for the whole page. When I click a link corresponding update panel appears and it shows a gridview. Once the user updates the grid and click submit button the grid view updates with latest data. But the problem is the panel size gets increased and the grid has moved towards bottom of the page.

```
 <tr>
  <td>  
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelMenu" runat="server">   
                 <ContentTemplate>
  <table>            
    <tr>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlNeedApproval" Visible="false" runat="server" Height="480px" Width="800px" >
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 665px">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelApproval" runat="server">
                  <ContentTemplate>
                     <table class="EditTemplate" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="6" align="center">
                                <div id="Div9" style="width:800px;HEIGHT:450px">
                                    <igtbl:UltraWebGrid ID="uwgApproval" runat="server" 
                                        DisplayLayout-AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="800px" 
                                        DataKeyField="Approval_log_ID" OnInitializeRow="uwgApproval_InitializeRow">
                                        <Bands>
                                            <igtbl:UltraGridBand AllowUpdate="Yes"
                                                FixedHeaderIndicator="Button"  AllowRowNumbering="Continuous"  
                                                BaseTableName="Approval_log" DataKeyField="Approval_log_ID" SortingAlgorithm="QuickSort">
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <igtbl:UltraGridColumn BaseColumnName="Approval_log_ID"  Hidden="True" Key="Approval_log_ID" DataType="System.Int32">
                                                        <Header Caption="Approval_log_ID"></Header>
                                                    </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>                                                  
                                                    <igtbl:TemplatedColumn AllowUpdate="Yes" Type="DropDownList" BaseColumnName="Approval_Status"  Key="Approval_Status" >
                                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                                            <div nowrap>Approve/Reject</div>
                                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <CellTemplate>
                                                           <asp:DropDownList ID="cboApprovalStatus" Width="110px" runat="server" onchange="SetApprovalStatus(this);">
                                                               <asp:ListItem  value="2"><--Select One--></asp:ListItem>
                                                                <asp:ListItem  value="0">Reject</asp:ListItem>
                                                                <asp:ListItem  value="1">Approve</asp:ListItem>
                                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                                        </CellTemplate>
                                                     </igtbl:TemplatedColumn>  
                                                     <igtbl:UltraGridColumn BaseColumnName="APPROVAL_TYPE" Key="APPROVAL_TYPE" Hidden="true">
                                                        <Header Caption="Type">
                                                            <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="1" />
                                                        </Header>
                                                        <Footer>
                                                            <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="1" />
                                                        </Footer>
                                                    </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
                                                    <igtbl:UltraGridColumn BaseColumnName="Assigned_By" Key="Assigned_By" Hidden="true">
                                                        <Header Caption="Assigned_By"></Header>
                                                    </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
                                                    <igtbl:UltraGridColumn BaseColumnName="CommonKey" Key="CommonKey" Hidden="true">
                                                        <Header Caption="CommonKey"></Header>
                                                    </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
                                                </Columns>
                                            </igtbl:UltraGridBand>
                                        </Bands>
                                    </igtbl:UltraWebGrid>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                       <tr> 
                            <td colspan="6" align="center">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnApprovalSubmit" CssClass="inputbut" OnClick="btnApprovalSubmit_serverclick" runat="server" Text="Submit" ></asp:Button>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnApprovalReset" CssClass="inputbut" OnClick="btnApprovalReset_serverclick" runat="server" Text="Reset"  ></asp:Button> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel> 
            </td>
        </tr>


    </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Put your code here. Be more spesific when you asking a question. Read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: My issue is though the functionality is working, the design collpases.Grid should be fixed in the top where it was initially before update.

Comment: something wrong with your html <table><tr><asp:UpdatePanel...

Comment: You have two UpdatePanels, one is enough for what you do, remove the inside UpdatePanel and try again.

Comment: @Aristos: As you said, I changed my property of my update panel for the whole page to updatemode=conditional. Now its working fine.Thank you.

Comment: @sachin then I make it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see on that code that you have two `UpdatePanels` the one inside the other. This can caush issues, the one is enough - the UpdatePanel of the outside is also update the inner content of the other.

Its better to remove the inner UpdatePanel, and in general you use more UpdatePanels only you goin to distinct some actions. Also remember that what is inside the UpdatePanel is going to change, so the content of it must be a fully complete render code and not a part of it, for example, not a part of a table, but the full table.